# What's the point of vote animations?

Tags: discussion

Exactly what it says on the tin.

I may be a bit out of date, but can someone explain to me the reasoning behind them?

[image]

Comment: I feel bad for the chap I just up voted and then undid about 4 times to see all the animations.

Comment: @KronoS I always get the same animation :(

Comment: @AndrejaKo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85617/can-we-get-a-gallery-of-unicorns/85618#85618

Comment: Check your calendar.

Comment: how come I don't see any animations?

Comment: @rzlines It appears that they have been removed in the meantime.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We have a rendering bug on some of our sites (around the voting controls) that we can't fix (our designer has to do that, but he's on vacation, making a "bacon kinds of the world" hike), so we decided to cover the glitch up.

Comment: So, it's a cover-up? :) Anyway, that explains the problem. I'll accept this answer as soon as dancing unicorns let me.

Comment: It'll be 6-8 weeks to gather all the samples.

Comment: Upvoted just to see a unicorn! Today I'll probably get the Suffrage tag...

Comment: What's the date today by the way?